# Reading values from arrayOfCheckboxes checked in JSP page and pass it to a method in the Spring controller

Tags: arrays, spring, jsp

Here is my JSP code

```
<% /* {"Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4"}; */
String[] groupSelection = (String[])request.getAttribute("group");      
for(int i = 0; i < groupSelection.length; i++)
{
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="<%= groupSelection[i]%>"> <%= groupSelection[i]%>
<%
}
%>
```

Now I wanted to read the array of groups selected and pass this array to a method in my Spring controller.
Here is my java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.RESULT_RETURN, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView result(Locale locale, Model model,
            @RequestParam(value="groupSelection") String[] groupsEleted) {
......
```

But this is not working, comes up with exception "HTTP Status 400 - Required String[] parameter 'groupSelection' is not present"
Please let me know how to access array of checkboxes selected in JSP from java.
Thanks.

Comment: I can view those parameters on the url using GET, like this: url/?Group1=on&Group2=on&Group4=on&_submit=Submit. but this array is not captured in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery attribute selector like.

```
$('input:checked');
```

So you will get object then make it as serialize like

```
$('input:checked').serialize();
```

Then you will get serialize values.

For more details [check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/patilharshal16/2w2b713o/1/)